Clarifying Spatial Derivatives for Operators within Quantum Field Theory
The following question arises from some confusion about operators in Quantum Field Theory. I previously asked it on Physics Stack Exchange, but the answers didn’t fully clarify my understanding. Therefore, I would like to ask mathematicians as well, hoping to get a precise definition of what the derivative of an operator means.
I would be incredibly grateful for any insights or explanations you could provide, and I sincerely thank you in advance for taking the time to help clarify my question.
Here the question starts:
Suppose that $\mathcal{O}(t,\mathbf{x})$ is an operator that commutes with itself at any point, i.e,
\begin{equation}
    [\mathcal{O}(t,\mathbf{x}),\mathcal{O}(t,\mathbf{y})]=0.
\end{equation}  Then, I need to calculate the commutator
\begin{equation}
    \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\mathcal{O}(t,\mathbf{x}),\mathcal{O}(t,\mathbf{y}) \right]
\end{equation} where $i=1,2,3$, meaning that only spatial derivatives are considered.
All answers indicate that this commutator is zero based on the fact that
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\mathcal{O}(t,\mathbf{y})=0
\end{equation} since $\mathcal{O}(t,\mathbf{y})$ does not depend on $\mathbf{x}$. My confusion starts here.
Why is the derivative of $\mathcal{O}(t,\mathbf{y})$ with respect to $x^i$ zero?
More specifically, what does "derivative of $\mathcal{O}(t,\mathbf{y})$" actually mean? After all, $\mathcal{O}$ is the operator that takes different values at different space-time points, while $\mathcal{O}(t,\mathbf{y})$ simply represents the value of the operator $\mathcal{O}$ evaluated at $(t,\mathbf{y})$. Thus, $\mathcal{O}(t,\mathbf{y})$ is just a constant operator, and its derivative should be zero of course. However, if this interpretation is correct, then we should also have  $\frac{\partial\mathcal{O}(t,\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_i}=0$ since $\mathcal{O}(t,\mathbf{x})$ would also be constant in this sense.  As far as I understand, this reasoning doesn’t seem to relate to the derivative in question.
In my view, what one should write instead is
\begin{equation}
    \partial_i\mathcal{O}
\end{equation} and if we need to evaluate it at point $\mathbf{y}$, then we may write
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial\mathcal{O}}{\partial x^i}\Bigr|_{(t,\mathbf{y})}.
\end{equation} So, what does
\begin{equation}
     \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\mathcal{O}(t,\mathbf{y})
\end{equation} actually mean?
I realize the notations have left me quite confused, and my question might seem trivial. I apologize in advance for any misunderstanding.
